# How to get out of this error in spring application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

```java
@PostMapping("/addStudent")
String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") Students student, Model model) {
  studentsRepository.save(student);

  return "index";
}
```

This code is not returning me to the index page, instead giving an error:

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Oct 18 20:32:54 IST 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try @ControllerAdvice

and @ExceptionHandler

then return your error page

reference docs: https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Comment: What can I do other than this

Comment: try catch your code and return error page. I think it's not a best solution